# Twitter OAuth1.0A Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter, oauth

I'm currently working on incorporating an authorization feature for Twitter following the approach described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter. I'm using Ajax to send my POST 'http' request, but I've been constantly running into a '401: Unauthorized' error. My code is below:

```
function getTweets() {
    var time = generateTimestamp(); 
    var nonce = generateNonce();
    var signature = generateSignature(time, nonce);
    var headers = {
          "Authorization": 'OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F", oauth_consumer_key="eEeAAz9fakedtAOlIUhPgQ", oauth_nonce="bbc34b2ca6faabogus6dfc025907fa334", oauth_signature="' + signature + '", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="' + time + '", oauth_version="1.0"'
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        dataType: "text",
        headers: headers,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success!");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jq) {
            alert("Request Failed.");
            console.log(jq.statusText);
        }
    });
}

function generateTimestamp() {
    var currentTime = new Date;
    currentTime = Math.floor(currentTime.getTime() / 1000);
    return currentTime;
}

function generateNonce() {
    var code = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        code += Math.floor(Math.random() * 9).toString();
    }
    return code;
}  

function generateSignature(timestamp, nonce) {
    var http_method = "POST";
    var base_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    var consumer_key = "eEeAAz9hUKtdjunkeIUhPgQ";
    var consumer_secret = "c7wHxnjubxVDcc5hYFqnotactuallymysecretWs2XazUFde0lPRBtBQ";
    var signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
    var token = "609493744-kNPzLKSI4Hg9NWQnopeFPb91eXFUutFm1nZ2hDk2";
    var token_secret = "15WOJS9Ji1AXsKRkyAZrxKdsalted5Gj5ZyEAb9aVrJxI";
    var version = "1.0";
    var parameter_string = "oauth_callback=" + encodeURIComponent(base_url) + "&oauth_consumer_key=" + consumer_key + "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce + "&oauth_consumer_key=" + consumer_key + "&oauth_signature_method=" + signature_method + "&oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp +"&oauth_version=" + version; 
    var base_string = http_method + "&" + encodeURIComponent(base_url) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(parameter_string);
    var signing_key = encodeURIComponent(consumer_secret) + "&";  
    var signature = encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, signing_key)));
    alert(signature);
    return signature;
}
```

Feel free to post below if there's any other information that would make this error clearer. Thanks.

Comment: why are you multiplying your random number by 9 when creating your nonce? just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a node.js library to mess around with the Twitter OAuth dance and API.  Code is [here, tweeter.js](https://github.com/jimschubert/tweeter.js)

You're welcome to walk through the logic for creating the header and signature (starting at line [348](https://github.com/jimschubert/tweeter.js/blob/master/lib/tweeter.js#L348) )

One thing I don't see in the code you've posted and which will make a huge difference is that the signature string must be generated to include the original header, then the header must be **rebuilt** with the generated string.  It's a huge pain and it took me a while to figure it out.

Although the code I wrote is geared toward node.js, you should be able to reuse a lot of the logic to meet your needs.

**EDIT**
I found a site called [hueniverse](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/) documented OAuth very well.   In fact, there is a utility [here](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/) to build your own headers for validating your logic (select the 'Create your own' radio button).

**EDIT 2**

To better explain including the `oauth_signature` value in the header, suppose you have all of the data up to this point:

```
var headerObj = {
    oauth_consumer_key="123456789",
    oauth_token="11111",
    oauth_nonce="asdfghjkl%3B",
    oauth_timestamp="1341852000",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_version="1.0"
};
```

You create the HMAC-SHA1 signature and receive: `"jBpoONisOt5kFYOrQ5fHCSZBGkI%3D"`

You would then add that return value to `headerObj`, giving you:

```
headerObj = {
    oauth_consumer_key="123456789",
    oauth_token="11111",
    oauth_nonce="asdfghjkl%3B",
    oauth_timestamp="1341852000",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_signature="jBpoONisOt5kFYOrQ5fHCSZBGkI%3D"
};
```

And this modified version of headerObj is what you build your HTTP headers from.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com:443
Authorization: OAuth realm="https://api.twitter.com/",
    oauth_consumer_key="123456789",
    oauth_token="11111",
    oauth_nonce="asdfghjkl%3B",
    oauth_timestamp="1341852000",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_signature="jBpoONisOt5kFYOrQ5fHCSZBGkI%3D"
```

*NOTE: I didn't verify the host/realm/port, so these are probably wrong. Check the API for those.*

The reason this is done is that on Twitter's side (this is an OAuth implementation detail), the `oauth_signature` value is removed and the rest of the header is hashed and its return value is compared to the value sent in `oauth_signature`.  It's sort of like a wax seal on an envelope... if the hash of the rest of the header doesn't match the hash value you sent in `oauth_signature`, Twitter knows not to trust the sender or the contents.

*EDIT 2.5*

I'm moving this from the comment to the answer.

If you check out [this line](https://github.com/jimschubert/tweeter.js/blob/master/lib/tweeter.js#L378) in tweeter.js, you'll see the logic.

```
   var signature = self.oauthSignature(method, path, headerObj, query);
    headerObj.oauth_signature = qs.escape(signature);

    // concat the header object into a csv string
    var header = 'OAuth realm="Twitter API",';
    var oauthParts = [];
    for (var h in headerObj) {
        oauthParts.push(h + '="'+headerObj[h]+'"');
    }
    header+= oauthParts.join(',');

    //...

    return header;
```

This bit of code does as I've explained in EDIT 2, by converting a JSON object into `key="value"` strings stored in `oauthParts[]`, then joins each element in that array into a single comma-separated string which begins with `OAuth realm="Twitter API",`

Comment: Forgot to mention, the project I linked to doesn't handle caching of any tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your response; I did have a question for you:

You mentioned that I should include the 'original header' to generate the signature string; however, one parameter of the header is the signature itself, which is a bit of a paradox. Could you clarify this step? I think I may be considering the wrong header/am not quite sure how to incorporate the header into the signature. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHang sure. I updated the answer to make it a little more clear.